# What does professionalism mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I used this link
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/professionalism?q=professionalism+

Amazon CEO Jeff Bezos shared an essay by writer Shenequa Golding about attempting to maintain professionalism after witnessing black men and women being killed.

Source: https://www.businessinsider.com/billionaires-respond-george-floyd-protests-musk-gates-bezos-soros-zuckerberg-2020-6

Comment: According to Merriman-Webster Learner's Dictionary, **professionalism** means "the skill, good judgment, and polite behavior that is expected from a person who is trained to do a job well".

Comment: It always means the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right with the dictionary definition, but in this precise context, I would say it means *professional conduct*, or a *professional attitude*.

Being "professional" in a workplace involves many things including being fair, impartial etc. Most would also agree that being professional also involves not allowing personal feelings to cloud judgement, and not bringing matters from one's personal life into the workplace.

The point seems to be that the essay is about not allowing an emotive and distressing incident (and the possible repercussions) to affect one's conduct and productivity at work, and / or not bringing related matters into the workplace.